# how do I successfully to using hexagonsdk

Tags: windows, hexagonal-architecture, hexagon-dsp

when i install hexagon sdk 5.1.0.0 using QPM, error occured "hexagonsdk5x_jre.5.2.0.0.windows-x86.exe hexagonsdk5x_jre.5.2.0.0.windows-x86.exe was not installed". then install these deps using "java -jar .\utils\scripts\depDl.jar -c cmake/devcon/fullndk..." -> cannot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jUq0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eC1G.png)
there is not launch_hexagon_ide.cmd file in rootDir
[image]

how to solve these problems？and using hexagonsdk for development.

[image]

Comment: What are your maven and eclipse versions?

Comment: there is no maven and eclipse. just because eclipse will be installed when installing SDK by click option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there was an interruption in your internet connection or your internet connection is blocking ping. You can try to reinstall the Hexagon SDK with ping enabled and an internet connection.
If you can't have a continuous internet connection, or you cannot enable ping, you will need to download the various components of the SDK separately as described in the Hexagon SDK documentation: file:///C:/Qualcomm/Hexagon_SDK/5.1.0.0/docs/tools/setup.html#defining-a-source-to-install-from

You should be able to find the document at your install location. Reinstall the SDK if you cannot find this. If you are downloading the components to a separate location, you will need the .json file mentioned in the doc and present in the %TEMP% folder, otherwise you can proceed without using the .json, it should pick it up from the server mentioned in the doc.

For example, in your case you need Eclipse downloaded. Eclipse further depends on JRE and cmake4eclipse. These can be downloaded separately from the links mentioned in the above doc or using the following commands: (Please note the java location here. Your java installation might not be compatible. The below mentioned path has the proper version of java you would need to download the component. If the Tool is not downloaded, reinstall the SDK, or maybe try with your own java)

```
C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\5.1.0.0\tools\HEXAGON_Tools\8.5.13\Tools\java\jre\bin\java.exe -jar %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%\utils\scripts\depDl.jar -t %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT% -j C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\hexSDKCFG.json -c JRE
C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\5.1.0.0\tools\HEXAGON_Tools\8.5.13\Tools\java\jre\bin\java.exe -jar %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%\utils\scripts\depDl.jar -t %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT% -j C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\hexSDKCFG.json -c cmake4eclipse
C:\Qualcomm\Hexagon_SDK\5.1.0.0\tools\HEXAGON_Tools\8.5.13\Tools\java\jre\bin\java.exe -jar %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%\utils\scripts\depDl.jar -t %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT% -j C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\hexSDKCFG.json -c Eclipse
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. But when I install jre, JSON exception occured. The description of jre in the json file is as follows: "jre" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\jre-8u51-windows-x64.tar.gz"

Comment: The content of hexSDKCFG.json is as follows：{
    "DependencyPaths" : {
        "minimalandroidndk" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\minimal_android-ndk-r19c-windows-x86_64.zip",
        "fullandroidndk" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\android-ndk-r19c-windows-x86_64.zip",
        "eclipse" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\eclipse-cpp-photon-R-win32-x86_64.zip",
        "gnuwin" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\gow-0.8.0.zip",
        "devcon" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\devcon.exe",
        "cmake" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\cmake-3.17.0-win64-x64.zip"
        "jre" : "D:\\sdk_deps\\jre-8u51-windows-x64.tar.gz"
        }
}

Comment: Another problem, there is no launch_hexagon_ide.cmd  file in %HEXAGON_SDK_ROOT%

Comment: Your JSON file needs to point to the location you have downloaded the component. You don’t seem to have the component downloaded locally, so the location should be the links mentioned the document. Replace the "D:\\path" in your JSON with the link mentioned in the document.
The component installation for jre and cmake4eclipse should work even without passing the JSON file name in the args. You can give that a try too.
You should see the launch_hexagon_ide.cmd after Eclipse component is installed successfully.

Comment: Now, I have successfully installed jre. Then when I install eclipse, some errors occured, "Please wait...
Cmake4Eclipse IDE: Installing from jar:file:/./tools/hexagon_ide/ide_plugins/photon/cmake4eclipse-2.1.3.zip!/
Installation failed. Unable to load repositories.
Cmake4Eclipse IDE:dependencies Installation Done...
Hexagon plugin Installation from jar:file:/./tools/hexagon_ide/ide_plugins/photon/IDE.zip!/ Installation failed.
Unable to load repositories.

Hexagon plugin Installation Done...
You are using the older version of Hexagon, please update the plugins."

Comment: Even if the above error is reported, the launch_hexagon_ide.cmd file is still generated in the root directory of the SDK, but it is opened by Eclipse IDE, instead of Hexagon IDE. The cmake4eclipse file is downloaded from github: "https://github.com/15knots/cmake4eclipse/tree/v.2.1.3".  And the other components of the SDK are downloaded as described in the Hexagon SDK documentation.